# Porting a Java app that uses AWT and Swing for drawing movies to the server-side

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am working with some code that writes animated output to the desktop using AWT and Swing features. It draws using 2D graphics and renders text in fonts.

This code can use the Java Media Framework to save the animationto movie files.

I would like to port this code to a pure server-side environment, for working with a Web UI. The drawing code could either run inside the servlet container, or outside as a command-line program. (Or I could opt not to use a servlet container and instead use the newer ways of running Java web servers from the command line.)

Can I use AWT and Swing drawing features without starting the X Window System on the server?

Comment: you mean you want to run the code without opening Java container?

Comment: I want to run the code without opening the X Window System or a GUI. I can make it run in a container, or, directly as a console app.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The article [*Using Headless Mode in the Java SE Platform*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html) outlines the limitations imposed on such applications.

As a concrete example [`JFreeChart`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info) is a graphic program widely used in both desktop and servlet contexts. For the latter, any of several [`ChartUtils`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartUtils.html) may be used to stream rendered content in a headless environment.

Alternatively, although deprecated, consider [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) to deploy an existing Swing application, for example the `JFreeChart` demo seen [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html).

Addendum: This Oracle forum [thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1280600) suggests that the Java Media Framework can indeed throw `HeadlessException`; a suggested workaround is to specify a particular system property value:

```
-Dawt.toolkit=sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit
```

This `JFreeChart` forum [thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20160323222859/http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=1012) suggests [`Xvfb`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) or [`vnc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) as alternatives when `headless` mode is not available.

Comment: Thanks. Will this also work for moving animation? Sorry it wasn't clear in my description (now edited).

Comment: I've elaborated above, although I'd welcome any more dispositive results.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like AWT/Swing needs a fake graphics system to work with.

Comment: Yes, for any heavyweight components that require a host peer; but all the [JAVA 2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) features remain available.