# Java: Run Applet on headless server

Tags: java, applet, awt, headless

My question is pretty simple. Let's say that this is my entire codebase, and I cannot change it:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Example1b extends java.applet.Applet
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      Frame f = new Frame("Example 1b");

      Example1b ex = new Example1b();

      f.add("Center", ex);

      f.pack();
      f.show();
   }
}
```

Is there any tricks I can do to make this run on a web server without display? I know that java.applet.Applet won't work in headless mode, so can I stub the awt classes, or do some other trickery?

Comment: Thanks, running through them now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `Applet` runs in the client's browser, applet viewer or IDE. Some alternatives to headless mode on the server are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13985919/230513), including JWS, VNC and Xvfb.