# Running Swing-Tests remotely on a Windows7-Jenkins-Slave

Tags: java, swing, jenkins, windows-7-x64

I already managed to set up a Jenkins-Slave on a Windows 7(x64) machine. I'm also able to attach Jobs to the slave and they get succesfully executed. But all tasks seem to be running in headless mode!? We have some graphical Swing-Tests that are starting a Swing GUI and executing Macros on it. When executing the corresponding Maven-Command manualy on the slave-node

```
mvn -B -f C:\Jenkins\workspace\3-Test-Script-GUI-Test\pom.xml clean test
```

everything works fine, but when triggering this command via Jenkins the Swing-GUI doesn't open and the tests fail.

Are jenkins-jobs by default triggered in headless mode or is there any other configuration that could help me to resolve this problem?

The jenkins-slave.xml looks as follows:

```
  <executable>javaw.exe</executable>
  <arguments>-Xrs  -jar "%BASE%\slave.jar" -tcp %BASE%\port.txt</arguments>
```

Answer (score 2):

The manual tests may (appear to) work when run from an X11 session running on the host, as the X server functions as valid peer for AWT components. Some alternatives (VNC, Xvfb) for [headless mode](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html) are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13985919/230513).