# Java headless exception when I start java using a linux daemon

Tags: java, linux, swing, exception, daemon

I have a linux daemon that starts a java instance for each user that is logged on the system.

I use the followig command to start the java application for each user:

```
cd /home/user/java_path/ && sudo -u user /opt/jdk1.7.0_17/java -jar software.jar &
```

The java application monitors a folder and opens a frame for authentication when a new document is create. Each java application reads only the users files (by a name pattern). When tries to open a frame, but I get this error (on a log):

> No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
>
> java.awt.HeadlessException: ...

When I execute the java application in a regular command line (terminal), this works well.

I saw also the export variables, using *export -p* command and the display variable is ok for all users logged.

Comment: Some workarounds are cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13985919/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code worked. To resolve that, I had need to export java variables and then starts the java application, in a sequence, like that: cd *path* && export DISPLAY=:0.0 && export USERNAME= *user* && sudo -u user javapath/java -jar app.jar >/dev/null 2>&1

Comment: I am working with GWT 2.8.1 version and  exported the DISPLAY=:0.0 but Iam still getting the headless exception after I set the -Djava.awt.headless=false option.

Answer (score 2):

Some java classes depend on having i.e. display device and if you don't have any(running without X-server), they fail with the error you're getting.
Run java with following parameter:

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

More info here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html

Comment: I try use this option, but isn't worked. The HeadlessException continues, but the message now is **null**.

Comment: When I used the option **-Djava.awt.headless=false**, java return this exception > **Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of DISPLAY variable ...**.

Comment: By "open a frame" you mean some GUI? This won't work. If you want to run it as a daemon, you should remove calls to some parts of AWT.

Comment: The code worked. To resolve that, I had need to export java variables and then starts the java application, in a sequence, like that: **cd _path_ && export DISPLAY=:0.0 && export USERNAME= _user_ && sudo -u _user_ javapath/java -jar app.jar >/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null &**

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");` or `-Djava.awt.headless=true` JVM arg