# Java 3D renders on vnc, not on monitor

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, java-3d

I have a program using Java3D that I'm running on a Raspberry Pi.  I've been running the Pi on my network and accessing it through VNC via another machine whilst I ironed out a few kinks in my program.

I now have it running, albeit a bit slowly, and wanted to try it in its eventual use case, by plugging the Pi into a monitor and running it standalone.

However, when I run the Pi on a monitor, the program will not start, and prints out the following error:

```
Canvas3D_createNewContext: couldn't make current

DefaultRenderingErrorListener.errorOccurred:
CONTEXT_CREATION_ERROR: Renderer: Error creating Canvas3D graphics context
graphicsDevice = X11GraphicsDevice[screen=0]
canvas = javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D[canvas0,0,0,252x231]
```

I don't know much about the rendering process in linux, but if anyone could suggest what might be different between what VNC does and what a normal X11 server does that could cause problems I'd be grateful.

I'm using Oracle Java 1.7.0_40 with Java 3D 1.5 on the latest release of Raspbian.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Using VNC means your setup is _not_ [headless](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html).

Comment: My mistake in terminology. Question edited.

Comment: Use `java -Djava.awt.headless=true` to see if your application can run headless or supply a head, e.g. VNC, XVFB, etc.

Comment: It throws a 'HeadlessException' if I try that.

Comment: Rather use the very latest version of Java3D. Java3D 1.5 was already obsolete when you posted your question. Switch to Java3D 1.6.0 with JOGL 2.3.2 to give it a chance to work.

Answer (score 0):

The article [*Using Headless Mode in the Java SE Platform*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html) describes the limitations imposed on applications intended to run in headless mode. For applications that cannot be usefully converted, some alternatives are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13985919/230513).