# RazorSQL not working?

Tags: java, swing, headless, razorsql

I am using RazorSQL and when I run it from my terminal it's not opening and throws the following exception:

```
java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:535)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:218)
    at load.RazorSQL.main(Unknown Source)
1389939280395: Unable to show launch screen: null
1389939280577: Attempting to load . . .
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.jgoodies.looks.plastic.PlasticLookAndFeel.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at load.c.z(Unknown Source)
    at load.c.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at load.c.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at load.RazorSQL.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
    at sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit.getScreenResolution(HeadlessToolkit.java:227)
    at com.jgoodies.looks.LookUtils.isLowResolution(Unknown Source)
    at com.jgoodies.look
```

It was working earlier but suddenly it has stopped working. What I can infer from the exception is that it's giving a swing error so it's GUI error. It's unable to open razorsql.png which is the opening icon.

Anyone has any idea about why is it not working?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Ubuntu?

Comment: @Nik: Yes, I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you have a running X-Windows on that machine?

Comment: Better to contact them directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that this error has nothing to do with razorsql. Check for java graphics lib is properly installed in your system or not. 
To be more sure install JRE. I hope that should solve your issue. Ubuntu has capability to install headless java.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
```

Answer (score 1):

For cross-platform use, [`RazorSQL`](http://www.razorsql.com) relies on the host platform's available Java installation. See [*Using Headless Mode in the Java SE Platform*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html) for details about why the GUI throws `HeadlessException` in the absence of an X window client. Some alternatives are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13985919/230513).

Comment: If you are starting Ubuntu on the command line, you can use [`startx`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/startx.1.html) to initialize an X session.