# Run JFrame in gui less linux os

Tags: java, linux, swing

Recently I switch to linux with no desktop os.

I have installed java successfull but when i run program of JFrame then it throws exception like

```
java.awt.HeadlessException
java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:159)
java.awt.Window.(Window.java:432)
java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:403)
javax.swing.JFrame.(JFrame.java:202)
```

now I could not understand how can I fix this problem?

I want to run JFrame & even I dont want to remove os as well.

thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you expect to use GUI components without a GUI system?

Comment: Maybe try charva? http://sourceforge.net/projects/charva/

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the OS doesn't have any desktop, only command line, where do you expect the window to be drawn? If the OS doesn't have desktop, then you can only use command line.

You can try Charva, as @BenjaminDale suggested, but that will offer only limited functionality.

Comment: but can't i add graphic package only for java??

Comment: Graphic package must draw on something, but in your case there is nothing to paint on.

Answer (score 1):

Swing can only work with os supporting desktop (head / screen). In the case of headless os, I can't understand any use case of JFrame.

So you'll either have to get rid of JFrame from your program (which seems logical (there is no desktop)) or run it on an os with a head :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: **you'll either have to get rid of JFrame from your program**
i dont understand this statement.

Comment: That statement came from the question 'Why would you need a JFrame (which is a UI component) in an os which is headless'. You can't display anything anyways right?

Comment: I just want to make my own file manager in my os(without gui base os) because file manager is very tedious in linux.

Comment: It's a nice idea, but if the os does not support gui, then your file manager also can't have a gui. So at least JFrame can't be used.

Answer (score 1):

The article [*Using Headless Mode in the Java SE Platform*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html) describes the limitations imposed on applications intended to run in headless mode. For applications that cannot be usefully converted, some alternatives are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13985919/230513), including xvfb and vnc.