# Java GUI java.awt.headless exception ubuntu

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu

While trying to fix the same error posted in this thread:
[Java Can't connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:10.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165761/java-cant-connect-to-x11-window-server-using-localhost10-0-as-the-value-of-t)

I now have a java.awt.headless exception. I am accessing ubuntu 14.04 using Putty and I am not sure how to solve this java.awt.headless exception. I also do not have administrator permissions.

I got this exception after applying 
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");

EDIT: SOLVED
I followed a youtube video link, which basically explained that I have to set up SSH X11 port forwarding.

Find and download the software Xming and make sure its running before you start Putty
In Putty, under SSH in the menu on the left, expand the sub-options and click on X11. Check the "Enable X11 forwarding" box and you're good to go.

My reference: 
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLAYfwUPj7s

Comment: Some alternatives are cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13985919/230513).