# JavaFX SwingNode HeadlessException

Tags: java, swing, testing, javafx, headless

We've been working on building some integration tests for our JavaFX program and the one pain point we've been running into is that JavaFx's SwingNode seems to throw whenever operating in a testing environment even when using TestFX and Monocle's headless mode.

Our project uses some lightweight Swing code that seems to work fine on it's own in headless tests however as soon as any swing components get included in a javafx view using a swingnode, everything seems to blow up.

Ideally we'd like these tests to run each time we build the project along with our test suite on all machines however as a temporary fix we are making these test cases manual-run only on our windows machines and using Xvfb on linux machines + CI.

Below is a minimal example demonstrating the issue (running on JDK 11 with JavaFX 11 however in our main codebase I've also verified the issue appears on JDK 17 with JavaFX 17 as well):

`build.gradle.kts`

```
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestExceptionFormat

plugins {
    application
    id ("org.openjfx.javafxplugin") version "0.0.10"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.1")
    testImplementation("org.testfx:testfx-junit5:4.0.16-alpha")
    testImplementation("org.testfx:openjfx-monocle:jdk-11+26")
}

javafx {
    version = "11"
    modules("javafx.controls", "javafx.swing")
}

application {
    mainClass.set("test.example.SwingNodeExample")
}

tasks.named<Test>("test") {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperties = mapOf(
        "java.awt.headless" to true,
        "testfx.robot" to "glass",
        "testfx.headless" to true,
        "glass.platform" to "Monocle",
        "headless.geometry" to "1920x1080-32",
        "prism.order" to "sw"
    )
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat = TestExceptionFormat.FULL
    }
}
```

`src/test/java/test/example/SwingNodeTest.java`

```
package test.example;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.testfx.framework.junit5.ApplicationExtension;
import org.testfx.framework.junit5.Start;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.testfx.api.FxRobot;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

@ExtendWith(ApplicationExtension.class)
public class SwingNodeTest {

    private Group root;
    private SwingNode node;
    private JButton button;

    @Start
    private void start(Stage stage) {
        root = new Group();
        node = new SwingNode();
        root.getChildren().add(node);

        button = new JButton("Help");
        node.setContent(button);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }

    @Test
    void shouldInstance(FxRobot robot) {
    }

}
```

`src/main/java/test/example/SwingNodeExample.java`

```
package test.example;

public class SwingNodeExample {
    // Empty class to satisfy gradle.
}
```

---

Results:

```
user@localhost ~/tmp/javatest $ ./gradlew test

> Configure project :example
Project :example => no module-info.java found

> Task :example:test FAILED

SwingNodeTest > shouldInstance(FxRobot) FAILED
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.awt.HeadlessException
        at org.testfx.util.WaitForAsyncUtils.---- Delayed Exception: (See Trace Below) ----(WaitForAsyncUtils.java:0)

        Caused by:
        java.awt.HeadlessException:
        No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
            at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:208)
            at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:548)
            at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:423)
            at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:388)
            at java.desktop/sun.awt.LightweightFrame.<init>(LightweightFrame.java:62)
            at java.desktop/sun.swing.JLightweightFrame.<init>(JLightweightFrame.java:118)
            at jdk.unsupported.desktop/jdk.swing.interop.LightweightFrameWrapper.<init>(LightweightFrameWrapper.java:51)
            at com.sun.javafx.embed.swing.newimpl.SwingNodeInteropN.createLightweightFrame(SwingNodeInteropN.java:88)
            at com.sun.javafx.embed.swing.newimpl.SwingNodeInteropN.createLightweightFrame(SwingNodeInteropN.java:59)
            at javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode.setContentImpl(SwingNode.java:375)
            at javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode.lambda$setContent$5(SwingNode.java:347)
            at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
            at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
            at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
            at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
            at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
            at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
            at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
            at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
            at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
            at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
            at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
            at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

1 test completed, 1 failed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':example:test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///home/user/tmp/javatest/example/build/reports/tests/test/index.html

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

---

I understand "why" this is occurring in that SwingNode instantiates an internal helper class that throws when instantiated in a headless environment.

My question instead is: What is the technical reason that SwingNode is unable to be instantiated and loaded with Swing content without throwing in a Headless environment?

The follow-up would be: How could we work around this, either in the test suite or in the application itself (such as an alternative to `javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode`)? Like previously mentioned we have a temporary "hack" using Xvfb on *nix machines however on Windows there doesn't seem to be any real solution from what I can see.

---

Edit: I realised I forgot to mention why the tests can't be headless on Windows. With TestFx, the tests steal mouse + keyboard input and draw on the monitor itself. This makes the tests very fragile since they can be easily failed just by the developer interacting with their machine or another application triggering a popup or notification (such as MS Teams or Outlook).

Comment: If you look at the stack trace, you can see it is trying to create an awt.Window.  If you look at the [awt headless docs](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/headless.html), it says "Many components are affected if a display device, keyboard, or mouse is not supported. An appropriate class constructor throws a HeadlessException: Such heavyweight components require a peer at the operating-system level, which cannot be guaranteed on headless machines.".  An awt.Window is one of those components which is not supported.  I don't have a solution for you.

Comment: Some alternatives are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13985919/230513).

Comment: For your testing, you might consider a dedicated machine, VM or docker environment, either local or cloud based. Perhaps then you won’t get interference from outlook popups and such.  You can automate such testing using Jenkins and a Jenkins file in an appropriate pipeline, though that takes a little skill.